# Algorithms : Pizza Cutting

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

I'm trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-ways-of-cutting-a-pizza/

> Given a rectangular pizza represented as a rows x cols matrix
>   containing the following characters: 'A' (an apple) and '.' (empty
>   cell) and given the integer k. You have to cut the pizza into k pieces
>   using k-1 cuts.
>
> For each cut you choose the direction: vertical or horizontal, then
>   you choose a cut position at the cell boundary and cut the pizza into
>   two pieces. If you cut the pizza vertically, give the left part of the
>   pizza to a person. If you cut the pizza horizontally, give the upper
>   part of the pizza to a person. Give the last piece of pizza to the
>   last person.
>
> Return the number of ways of cutting the pizza such that each piece
>   contains at least one apple. Since the answer can be a huge number,
>   return this modulo 10^9 + 7.

The pizza consists of at most 50 rows and columns, and k <= 10.

For now, I have a very basic, brute force solution, which I plan to optimize later on.

Here's my code :

```
class Solution {
    long combos;
    public int ways(String[] pizza, int k) {
        Set<String> remaining = new HashSet<String>();
        this.combos = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < pizza.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < pizza[i].length(); j++) {
                char ch = pizza[i].charAt(j);
                if(ch == 'A') remaining.add(i + "," + j);
            }
        }

        getCombos(remaining, k - 1);
        return (int)(combos % (1000000007));
    }

    public void getCombos(Set<String> remaining, int k) {
        if(remaining.isEmpty()) return;
        if(k == 0) {
            combos++;
            return;
        }

        Set<Integer> seenCol = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> seenRow = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(String apple : remaining) {
            String[] posStr = apple.split(",");

            int i = Integer.parseInt(posStr[0]);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(posStr[1]);

            // cut below this
            Set<String> below = getBelow(i, j, remaining);
            if(!seenRow.contains(i))  {seenRow.add(i);getCombos(below, k - 1);}

            // cut right
            Set<String> right = getRight(i, j, remaining);
            if(!seenCol.contains(j)) {seenCol.add(j);getCombos(right, k - 1);}
        }
    }

    public Set<String> getBelow(int i, int j, Set<String> remaining) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String apple : remaining) {
            String[] coords = apple.split(",");
            if(Integer.parseInt(coords[0]) > i) result.add(apple);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Set<String> getRight(int i, int j, Set<String> remaining) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String apple : remaining) {
            String[] coords = apple.split(",");
            if(Integer.parseInt(coords[1]) > j) result.add(apple);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This doesn't pass the following test case : [".A..A","A.A..","A.AA.","AAAA.","A.AA."]
5

The expected result is 153, however, my code returns 141.

I can't figure out why and would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: without running the program myself, so this is probably not a full answer, but one thing is that you are only cutting next to an Apple,   Consider that bottom row “A.AA.”, so you cut after columns 1,3 and 4 (although 4 turns out to be invalid).   However, you are missing that you can also cut after column 2 !

Comment: You need to focus the question, as it currently stands, this question should be closed as `Needs debugging details: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.` Can you please add more details and focus the problem to a much smaller part of the code / algorithm ?

Comment: @racraman right. Dumb mistake from me! Mind adding this as an answer, so I can accept it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only cutting adjacent to an apple, but cutting between apples can also be valid.

For example, consider that bottom row “A.AA.”, so you cut after columns 1,3 and 4 (although 4 turns out to be invalid). However, you are missing that you can also cut after column 2 !